# How to continue the program even after evaluating the condition to true in if else loop in python?

Tags: python

I am implementing the scenario in which i have multiple if,elif,else loops.My problem is when the condition met ,its coming out of the program and exits the program .

Expected Behavior - After successful completion it should not exit but rather again show me the options to select .Only after pressing something like cntrl+c it should exit out the program.

```
class Manager:
    def __init__(self):
        self.not_useful_tests = []
        self.sdsf

   def sdsf(self):

       try:
            input = raw_input()
            if input == 'x':
                self.not_useful_tests.append(0)
            else:
                if input == 1:
                   verify = self.ABC()
                   return verify
                if input == 2:
                    verify = self.xyz()
                    return verify
                if input == 3:
                    verify = self.hyg()
                    return verify
                if input == 4:
                  verify = self.fgh()
                   return verify
                if input == 5:
                   verify = self.qwe()
                   return verify

        except KeyboardInterrupt as e:
            print "Exception caught : " + str(e)
            return None
```

How to achieve this beahvior ? What to add in the code so as to achieve the task ?

Comment: use Lambda statement. This Optimise more than for-Loop

Comment: Is the code supposed to only check for `'x'`. Since your using `raw_input` in Python 2.7, there's never going to be an integer value.

Comment: @EshanChattaraj no, lambdas are not faster than loops in Python. Function calls are incredibly expensive.

Comment: @EshanChattaraj - WIll you please provide little detailed solution for this ?

Comment: @EdwardMinnix - No code is not supposed to check only for x .It should check integer as well.Sorry its typo.It should check both.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To repeat something while some condition is true, use a `while` loop:

```
while True:
    input = raw_input()
    if input == 1:
        return 'some value'
    if input == 2:
        return 'some other value'
```

If you don't want to return a function result, but rather want to continue execution outside of the loop, i.e. 'break out of the loop' use `break`:

```
while True:
    input = raw_input()
    if input == 1
        print('doing something')
        break
    if input == 2
        print('doing something else')
        break
print('Continuing here')
```

And if that's what you want, you can also set a condition to end the loop like this:

```
result = None
while result is None:
    input = raw_input()
    if input == 1:
        result = 'x'
    if input == 2:
        result = 'y'
print('will continue here if result has a value')
```